# EmberJS View - detect if all children views have been rendered

Tags: javascript, callback, ember.js, view, render

Scenario:

- Collection of notes (async-loaded) is rendered
- Two views: NoteView that represents list of notes and NoteOnListView that represents single note
- I have to run some code (masonry.js) to lay them, but it requires all notes to be rendered first, it needs to know count and properties of those children

I have a template, *notes.hjs*:

```
{{#each note in controller}}
    {{view App.NoteOnListView}}
{{/each}}
```

And views:

```
App.NotesView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('the list has been rendered');
    }
});

App.NoteOnListView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('a note has been inserted');
    },
    afterRender: function() {
        console.log('a note has been rendered');
    }
});
```

Console output:

```
the list has been rendered 
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/notes"
a note has been rendered
a note has been inserted
a note has been rendered
a note has been inserted
// ... 
a note has been rendered
a note has been inserted
// This is where I need to run code!
```

I have some possible solutions to this problem, but all of them look hacky. Is there a nice way I can tell NotesView to wait until all its children are rendered?

Answer (score 12):

If you change your strategy to subclassing [Ember.CollectionView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html) you could use the following approach to receiving notification that your child views have finished rendering.

```
App.CV = Ember.CollectionView.extend( {
    itemViewClass : Ember.View.extend( {
        templateName : 'item'
    } ),

    onChildViewsChanged : function( obj, key ){
        var length = this.get( 'childViews.length' );
        if( length > 0 ){
            Ember.run.scheduleOnce( 'afterRender', this, 'childViewsDidRender' );
        }
    }.observes( 'childViews' ),

    childViewsDidRender : function(){
        //child views have finished rendering!     
    }
} );
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ethan_selzer/bwyeT/2/) that demonstrates this technique in Ember 1.0 RC2.

For more information on Ember.run.scheduleOnce see the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_scheduleOnce).

Comment: Great answer. It might be useful to use `scheduleOnce` instead of `schedule` to avoid accidentally calling childViewsDidRender more than once in the same run loop.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried approach with the collection view. The problem is, when i changed the class type to CollectionView, the view is not bound to route and is not rendered. I would like it to be used just as default view but I didn't find any resources on web how to do it. CollectionView documentation suggests that the class is used for static items and this is not my use case. BTW, at the moment, I call Masonry every time when I render item, it works fine.

Comment: Wow, this is great! I'm going to have to check out `Ember.run`. How does the `"afterRender"` part work?

Comment: @Knownasilya See the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/1e942ee6d560005a4e47e0ca3ea6fe3c280178cf/packages/ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js) for more information.